# Compare two larges data set using Python

Tags: python, json, list, algorithm, csv

I'm comparing line by line 2 files

One in JSON likes this:

```
{firstname: "xxx", lastname: "xxx"}
{firstname: "yyy", lastname: "yyy"}
```

One in csv likes this:

```
firstname;lastname;
xxx;xxx
yyy;yyy
```

Both lists are ordered by firstname, i've created 2 nested loop to store the index and the count of matches like below:

```
i = j = 0
chunks = []
while i < len(list_json):
    matched = 0
    while j < len(list_csv):
        if list_json[i]['firstname'][0] < list_csv[j][0][0]:
            j = 0
            break
        if ist_json[i]['firstname'] == list_csv[j][0]:
            matched += 1
            # more thing here 
            j += 1
     chunck.append((i,matched)
```

My problem is both file are about 1 M lines, and it take too long (more than 24h).
Do you have any ideas to solve this quickly ?

Comment: I would recommend using ```pandas```, a library made specifically for tabular data manipulations. Or ```Dask``` if you need parallelization.

Comment: There are numerous errors in your example code, please fix them.  Are there duplicates in either dataset ? both datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [{'firstname': "aaa", 'lastname': "bbb"},
     {'firstname': "xxx", 'lastname': "xxx"},
     {'firstname': "xxx", 'lastname': "yyy"},
     {'firstname': "yyy", 'lastname': "xxx"},
     {'firstname': "yyy", 'lastname': "yyy"},
     ]

b = [['xxx','xxx'],
     ['xxx','xxx'],
     ['yyy','yyy'],
     ['zzz','zzz']]

list_json = a
list_csv = b
```

You had some of your logic wrong and were changing indices at the wrong time.  I think this fixes your solution. Your solution counts first name matches only - I added a test for first and last name match.

```
i = j = 0
chunks = []
f_and_l_chunks = []
while i < len(list_json):
    matched = 0
    f_and_l_matched = 0
    fjson,ljson = list_json[i]['firstname'],list_json[i]['lastname']
    while j < len(list_csv):
        fcsv,lcsv = list_csv[j][0],list_csv[j][1]
        #print(f'i:{i} j:{j} | {fjson},{fcsv}')
        if fjson[0] < fcsv[0]:  # sorted by first name so short circuit 
            break
        if fjson == fcsv:    # compare first only like your example
            #print('          matched')
            matched += 1
        if (fjson,ljson) == (fcsv,lcsv):    # compare first and last
            f_and_l_matched += 1
        j += 1
    chunks.append((i,matched))
    f_and_l_chunks.append((i,f_and_l_matched))
    i += 1
    j = 0
```

---

I am pretty sure a less-than comparison between two strings is just as fast comparing the complete strings as comparing the first characters.

```
        if fjson[0] < fcsv[0]:  # sorted by first name so short circuit 
            break
```

is as *efficient* as

```
        if fjson < fcsv:  # sorted by first name so short circuit 
            break
```

---

Seems I misunderstood or didn't thoroughly read your question. Here is my first answer that is irrelevant but I'll leave it for posterity.

Obtain the first names from each container and use set intersection to find common items.

```
import operator
afn = map(operator.itemgetter('firstname'),a)
bfn = map(operator.itemgetter(0),b)
common = set(afn).intersection(bfn)

>>> common
{'xxx', 'yyy'}
```

Or matching first and last names uses the same process.

```
from operator import itemgetter
anames = map(itemgetter('firstname','lastname'), a)
bnames = map(itemgetter(0,1),b)
common = set(anames).intersection(bnames)
```

Comment: Great ! I think i could adapt your solution to work with firstname and lastname

Comment: @Minaro - you want to find common items where first and last name match?

Comment: Yes that was the idea, so your solution look likes a good approach but at the end I still need to loop over the original list